# Как заставить VSCode 2017 следить за изменением имени файла, и пути к файлу?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Пожалуйста подскажите, как заставить VSCode 2017 следить за изменением имени файла, и пути к файлу.
Например в WebStorm эта фича встроена. Экономит время при разработке. И мне не хватает этой фичи в VSCode.

Например в Nodejs я создал модуль. Импортировал его в другой модуль. Потом решил изменить название модуля, или перекинул его в другую папку.

Все сломалось. Нужно вспоминать в каких файлах я импортировал этот файл, и руками править имя файла, и путь к файлу.

Comment: Для таких действий, что Вы описали, мне кажется везде руками пути надо будет править....А так, есть модуль `supervisor`, он следит за всеми файлами в корневом каталоге и папке `node_modules`. Может еще есть какие настройки для расширения - не знаю. Мне пока так хватает. Устанавливаете его глобально и запускаете приложение через него: `supervisor app.js`. После каждого нового сохранения файла в наблюдаемом окружении он будет перезапускать исполняемый файл. Правда если создать новый файл, то прийдетmся руками перезапустить `supervisor`

Comment: Дмытрык, спасибо за ответ. Но это совсем не то. Модуль Supervisor следит за изменением кода в файлах. Я пользуюсь другим модулем Nodemon.

Comment: а Вы хотите, чтобы среда разработки сама меняла путь или имя подключаемого модуля в запускаемом файле?

Comment: Да! В WebStorm эта фича встроена. К хорошему привыкаешь быстро. И мне не хватает этой фичи в VSCode.

Comment: Понимаю Вас) . Я не знал, что такое есть. SublimeText пользуюсь.

Comment: Попробуй WebStorm. Тебе понравится. Единственный минус, она платная.

Comment: В WebSrotm много полезных фич в коробке. Например она показывает какие переменные объявлены, но нигде не используются. И много других.